# How to access to the elements of HashMap in HandleBars (hbs) file for Rust

Tags: html, rust, handlebars.js, hbs

I have a variable defined as `HashMap` in rs file:

```
sampleDir: HashMap<String, String>
```

and is initialized as the following (for example), it's two dimensional:

| First | Second |
| --- | --- |
| aa | ba |
| ab | bb |
| ac | bc |

```
sampleDir: HashMap::from([((&"aa").to_string(), (&"ab").to_string()),
                    ((&"ba").to_string(), (&"bb").to_string()),
                    ((&"ca").to_string(), (&"cb").to_string())].iter().cloned().collect())
```

I'm trying to access to those two elements in `sampleDir` in hbs file (for example):

```
{{#each sampleDir as |s|}}
        <tr>
            <th>
                how can I access to the first element? i.e. aa, ba, ca
            </th>
            <td style="width: 100%;">
                how can I access to the second element? i.e. ab, bb, cb
            </td>
        </tr>
{{/each}}
```

I use `this` like the following, but it only access to the second element, i.e. ab, bb, cb:

```
{{#each sampleDir as |s|}}
            <tr>
                <th>
                    {{this}}
                </th>
                <td style="width: 100%;">
                    {{this}}
                </td>
            </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation, here is the solution:

```
{{#each sampleDir as |s|}}
        <tr>
            <th>
                {{@key}}
            </th>
            <td style="width: 100%;">
                {{this}}
            </td>
        </tr>
{{/each}}
```